# How to read a pdf from URL in the native pdf reader without saving it in phone memory (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, pdf

Please tell me a way so that i can implement reading a PDF (URL) in the native pdf reader app without saving it in the phone memory. I tried reading it with Google Doc method (embedding the pdf URL with Google Doc Prefix) but thats a slow way of doing it. So please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, Android does not have a "native pdf reader app". Some Android devices ship with a PDF viewer. Some do not. Second, it is not possible to view a PDF hosted on the Internet without downloading *something*. I recommend that you edit your question and explain, in greater detail, what you mean by "without downloading it".

Comment: @CommonsWare Always sticking around ;) It's true, there is no way to read the PDF without downloading it (at least the text of it). We will need you to be more specific.

Comment: @CommonsWare bro i've edited my question. What i want is , I want to read the pdf URL without saving it in the phone memory, ! And by Native pdf reader i meant any of the pdf reader app installed in the phone (Whether its inbuilt or not)

Comment: @CommonsWare I've also tried emedding the pdf url with google docs viewer prefix and running it in WebView ! But that's quite slow, So i wanted it to get opened in the pdf reader app (already installed in the phone.)

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to download the PDF to a `byte[]`, then create a `ContentProvider` that makes that `byte[]` available to other apps via `openFile()`. Then, use a `Uri` pointing to your PDF in the `ContentProvider` with `ACTION_VIEW` to open up a standalone PDF viewer app.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.3/ContentProvider/Pipe) demonstrates the basic technique. In my case, my PDF comes from a file and a `FileInputStream`, but you could use a `ByteArrayInputStream` instead.

However:

- This can only be done for small PDF files, as you do not have heap space for a large `byte[]`
- A device may not have any PDF viewer app
- A user may not have access to any PDF viewer app, even if the device has one (e.g., user is running as a restricted profile on a secondary account)
- Once your process terminates, the PDF is gone
- Some PDF viewers will not support your `ContentProvider`, because they need their stream to be seekable, and yours will not be (since it is not backed by a file)

Writing the PDF to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), then using `FileProvider`, will improve your app's compatibility with PDF viewers and will handle much larger PDF files, without allowing the user to access the PDF file directly (except on rooted devices).

Comment: Thanks a lot for such decent explanation, and ya I will consider doing it Via internal storage. But can you please specify what you mean by "small PDF files" ?? 2 MB ?? 10 MB ??

Comment: @saurabhgupta: That will depend on the heap limit of your process and the fragmentation of your heap at the time you try downloading the PDF. It might be under 1MB. It might be over 10MB. To put it another way: I would never ship an app that did what you propose to do, as it will be far too unreliable.

Comment: Oh i see ! ok then .. I will now continue on the internal storage method. Thanks brother I've learned an important thing from you today.

Comment: bro i want you to answer my this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792275/fade-in-function-not-working-in-eclipse please.